# How to initialize the storage while originating a contract with storage type (pair (address %administrator) (unit %dummy))?

Tags: smart-contracts, tezos-client, storage, origination

The contract is meant to allow transfers only from the admin. I what to initialized the admin address at origination.

```
parameter (or (unit %default) (pair %admin_transfer (address %destination) (mutez %amount)));
storage   (pair (address %administrator) (unit %dummy));
code
  { ... }
```

I'm trying originate this with the tezos-client:

```
tezos-client originate contract admin-transfer transfering 10 from admin-address running path/admin-transfer  --init ??? --burn-cap 10
```

I tried several variations on `--init '(Pair "tz1..." unit)` with no luck. What is the argument that I need? If you know of any resources with multiple examples on how to use –init, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `unit` literal is capitalized `Unit`.

The following will work: `--init '(Pair "tz1..." Unit)'`.

Comment: Thank you! This is the answer. I don't have enough rep to up vote.

Comment: Btw, VisualTez is a useful tool for generating the Michelson values. Give it a try: https://visualtez.com/editor?h=a45e690cba6dcc5dfc6756e46cf0f65ec8056dbf&k=a6aa3b18d94e7696deb7

Comment: That's great, Thanks!